# Skype+Gnome 3 Answer directly in systray?

Tags: gnome, skype, gnome-shell-extension

Is there a way (as the pidgin integration plugin) to answer directly to skype conversations via the systray ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the pidgin-skype plugin in the first step.

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin-skype
```

Now start skype, set up your Skype-Account in pidgin as you would setup any other accout.
By installing the gnome shell extension you get the nice behaviour of empathy for pidgin and also for your configured skypeaccount (through pidgin)!

```
Pidgin Conversation Integration
```

[Pidgin Gnome Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/214/pidgin-conversation-integration/)

Comment: Well Pidgin is not really the feature I'm searching... I was thinking of something more... Elaborated. Like a script to execute when you receive a message, or something like that. Oh... I should code it in perl. :D